# Como faço um for em uma lista e altero resultados usandos javaEE

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Tenho um um objeto denominado(Banco) que tem varias contas, com saldo nessas contas faço pagamentos de varias despesas. o que eu quero é buscar todas as despesas pagas e dar baixa nas contas bancarias em um só movimento bancário, mas não estou conseguindo, método buscar:

```
public List<Banco> bancoRepository() { 
    //carregar lista para lançamento
    return manager.createQuery("from Banco", Banco.class).getResultList();
}
```

e criei esse método baixar

```
@Transactional
public Banco baixarPagamentos(Banco banco) {
    banco = bancos.porId(banco.getId());
    for (Banco banco1 : bancos.bancoRepository()) {
        banco.baixarPagamentos(banco1.getSaida());
    }

    return bancos.guardar(banco);
}
```

Mas não funcionou deu o seguinte erro

> Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for
>   update Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where
>   next_val=? 2017-12-12 09:53:45,850 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] HHH000346: Error
>   during managed flush [Validation failed for classes
>   [com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco] during persist time for
>   groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[  ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser
>   informado', propertyPath=nome, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=dataSaldoInicial, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=codigo, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=empresa, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=conta, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=agencia, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='deve ser informado',
>   propertyPath=operacao, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.almasystems.financeiro.model.Banco,
>   messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
>   ]]

Alguem poderia por favor da uma ideia.
se precisar de mais detalhes é só falar. 
ha tem mais esse é o trecho do html:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaBancos" paginator="true"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        value="#{lancamentoTributoBean.listaBancos}" var="banco"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="flase"
        style="margin-top: 5px" emptyMessage="" rows="10">

        <p:column headerText="NOME">
            <h:outputText value="#{banco.nome}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="SALDO">
            <h:outputText style="float: right;" value="#{banco.saldoInicial}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Baixar"
                action="#{cadastroBancoBean.baixarPagamentos}"
                update="tabelaBancos" process="tabelaBancos" />
            <h:outputText value="#{lancamentoTributoBean.total}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
            </h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Ja achei uma solução e muito obrigado aos caros colegas.

Criei um classe **BaixarPagamento** (com um lista de **ItemPagamento**), e um classe **ItemPagamento** com dois objetos(**Banco**; **BaixaPabamento**) e no bean
criei um for para a lista de bancos

```
this.listaBancos = bancos.bancoRepository();
```

que é carregada toda vez que atualizo a pagina html atraves do,

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{baixarPagamentoBean.inicializar}"
        type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>`
```

criei esse

```
public void adicionarBancos() {
    for (Banco banco : getListaBancos()) {
        item = new ItemPagamento();
        item.setBanco(banco);
        item.setBaixarPagamento(baixarPagamento);
        baixarPagamento.getItens().add(0, item);
    }
}
```

método para setar os valores da lista e quando clico no botão baixar ele executa a lista e o método,

```
public void salvar() {
    this.baixarPagamento = this.baixarPagamentoService.salvar(this.baixarPagamento);
    this.lancamentoBean.salvar();
    FacesUtil.addSuccessMessage("Baixa efetuada com sucesso!");
}
```

no meu bean, faz o cálculo.